# Number of keys between two keys

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

How would I find the number of keys occurring between two key values in a map ? Is there any way to accomplish this using iterators?

Comment: I haven't used map iterators enough to know, but `std::distance` might.

Comment: Have you taken a crack at this yourself, @user1543957? If so, it would help to know what you've tried so far. Use this [edit] link to add more details. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at map and some STL algirhtims:

```
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/
    lower_bound Return iterator to lower bound (public member function)
    upper_bound Return iterator to upper bound (public member function) 
    distance Calculates the number of elements between first and last.
```